# DockYard Ember Validations custom date validator

Tags: javascript, validation, ember.js

How do I implement a custom validator for a date (i.e. 04/11/2013 or 3.1.2001) using https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations. It seems I should be implementing the "Conditional Validators" to create a custom validator and return a boolean of true if it passed and false if it failed but I can't seem to be getting "unless" and "if" to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dockyard team is rolling out a new version of their validator:
https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations/issues/20